# Insert images using knitr::include_graphics in a for loop

Tags: r, knitr

````
```{r}
knitr::include_graphics(path = "~/Desktop/R/Files/apple.jpg/")
```
````

The above code chunk works fine. However, when I create a `for` loop, `knitr::include_graphics` does not appear to be working.

````
```{r}
fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "grape")
for(i in fruits){
  knitr::include_graphics(path = paste("~/Desktop/R/Files/", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
}
```
````

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a known issue [knitr include_graphics doesn't work in loop #1260](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1260).

A workaround is to generate paths to images within a for loop and `cat` them. To show final result `result = "asis"` is required.

````
```{r, results = "asis"}
fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "grape")
for(i in fruits) {
    cat(paste0("![](", "~/Desktop/R/Files/", i, ".jpg)"), "\n")
}
```
````

Here each iteration generates markdown path to graphics (eg, `"![](~/Desktop/R/Files/apple.jpg)"`)

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas. Using `print(paste0("![](", "~/Desktop/R/Files/", i, ".jpg)"))` worked, but I'm seeing `[1]"` and `"` around my image (i.e. I seem to be printing an extra set of quotation marks).

Answer (score 17):

`include_graphics()` has to be used in top-level R expressions as Yihui stated [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1260)

My workaround is this:

````
```{r out.width = "90%", echo=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
files <- list.files(path = paste0('../', myImgPath), 
                    pattern = "^IMG(.*).jpg$",
                    full.names = TRUE)

knitr::include_graphics(files, error = FALSE)

```
````

Comment: This solution works also with `files <- dir("path/to/files/", pattern = "pattern.*jpg$", full.names = TRUE)` instead of `list.files` too.

Comment: A note about _why_ this works. `list.files` outputs a vector of class character, which is what `include_graphics` expects. So files could be any character vector of file paths, or a `list` converted to `as.character(list_of_paths)`.
_e.g._
```{r}
fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "grape");
files <- lapply(X = fruits, FUN = function(fr){  file.path("~/Desktop/R/Files/",paste0(fr, ".jpg") ) } )
; knitr::include_graphics( as.character(files) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reply to the accepted answer by @pogibas, as I do not have enough reputation.
The markdown syntax can also be used to indicate the image width, a indicated [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html)

```
![A nice image.](foo/bar.png){width=50%}
```

This can be useful for rendering images from inside for loops or nested functions, thus avoiding the limitation of `knitr::include_graphics()`, which can only be used in top level R expressions. I hope it helps, it took me a little while to figure it out.