# render images in a loop inside Rmarkdown chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a bunch of pre-saved plots inside a folder.
I have a Rmarkdown(Flexdashboard) looping this folder and showing a picture per tab this way (an example taking just one)

````
```{r ,results="asis"}

list_plots <- list.files(plots_folder,pattern = ".png", full.names = TRUE)


  cat("  \n###",  "Tab Name  \n")
  knitr::include_graphics(list_plots[1])
  cat("  \n")

```
````

this worked flawlessly. My issue is when using a loop. The tabs are rendered but no plot inside. This way:

````
```{r ,results="asis"}
list_plots <- list.files(plots_folder,pattern = ".png", full.names = TRUE)

for(i in plots) {
  cat("  \n###",  "tab name  \n")
  knitr::include_graphics(i)
  cat("  \n")
}
```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert images using knitr::include\_graphics in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268623/insert-images-using-knitrinclude-graphics-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268623/insert-images-using-knitrinclude-graphics-in-a-for-loop), I'll drop here a fully reproducible code for `flexdashboard`:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

```{r create plots}
# reproducible example
tmp <- tempdir()
x <- lapply(5:10, function(x){
  png(file.path(tmp, paste0(x,".png")))
  plot(seq(x))
  dev.off()
})
```


```{r, results='asis'}
list_plots <- list.files(tmp, pattern = ".png", full.names = TRUE)

for(i in list_plots) {
  cat(sprintf("\n### tab name\n![](%s)\n", i))
}
```
````